# Join a table to bring in another field

Tags: sql, oracle

I currently have this query:

```
select f.chainid,count(f.player_uuid) as Favorites
from deals_player_favorite f
group by f.chainid
order by 2 desc
```

Which results in:

```
CHAINID            FAVORITES
25                 2771
2207               2282
3940               1954
```

etc...

I have another table called deals_deals, which also includes the CHAINID field. From this table, I want to join a field called VENUE in, so that each CHAIN ID has a Venue description, and the output would look like this

```
CHAINID    VENUE           FAVORITES    
25        Amazon.com        2771
2207       Walmart          2282
3940       CVS              1954
```

etc...

How would I properly join the venue field into the query, using CHAIN id as the key that is in both the deals_deals table and deals_player_favorite table.

I tried an inner join which resulted in way too many results.

The deals_deals table has the fields CHAINID and VENUE..

The deals_player_favorite table has the fields CHAINID and PLAYER_UUID, but does not include all of the CHAINIDs that the deals_deals table, only ones that have been accessed by a player_uuid.

SAMPLE DATA:

deals_deals table

```
VENUE        CHAINID
Walmart         235
Aeropostale     1467
Checker's       881
```

deals_player_favorite table

```
PLAYER_UUID         CHAINID
23rjior23-32fjdf     235
```

keep in mind that deals_player_favorite only includes specific CHAINIDs that have been clicked on, not ALL chainids....

Comment: Can you post your table structure for both tables and some sample data? That would probably help in getting an answer.

Comment: @bluefeet I updated the question with some sample data, does that help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your problem is that you are getting too many records in your count, then you might want to consider using a subquery and then joining the subquery to get the `venue`:

```
select f.chainid,
  v.venue,
  f.Favorites
from
(
  select chainid, count(player_uuid) Favorites
  from deals_player_favorite
  group by chainid
) f
inner join deals_deals v
  on f.chainid = v.chainid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08517/2)

The subquery will get your total favorites first, then using the `chainid` you will get the `venue`

Comment: @Stuave I am glad this worked.  For future reference when posting a question providing more details is better than less.  Also using a tool like sql fiddle to provide table structure and sample data is very helpful to those trying to answer.

Comment: Fair enough, I understand. Sometimes it's easy for me to see where I am having a problem, but for someone like you who has never been inside my database before, it's not as clear..noted for future posts.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT F.chainid, V.Venue, COUNT(f.player_uuid) as Favorites
FROM deals_player_favorite F
INNER JOIN Venues V
    ON F.chainid = V.chainid
GROUP BY F.chainid, V.Venue
ORDER BY COUNT(f.player_uuid) DESC
```

Comment: @Stuave Well, this query assumes that the column `chainid` of the table `Venues` is unique, obviously. You said on your question that we should use `chainid` as the common key

Comment: @Stuave if you misspoke then you can expect incorrect answers.

Comment: @Stuave Then please post the table definition of both of the tables that you need to `JOIN`, so we can post correct answers

Comment: @Stuave please post the actual table definitions and their associated "key" definitions so that a more accurate answer can be provided